# Is there a list of ghci abbreviated commands?

Tags: haskell, ghc, ghci

The [document](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/latest/docs/html/users_guide/ghci.html#ghci-commands) wrote,

> The command name may be abbreviated, with ambiguities being resolved in favour of the more commonly used commands

but I can't find exact list.

I know some of them but I want to know if there is the full list available. The command with `?` means ther are more than one suggesstions when tab-completion.

```
:a -> ?
:b -> ?
:c -> ?
:de -> ?
:e -> :edit
:for -> ?
:h -> :help
:i -> :info
:l -> :load
:m -> :module
:r -> :reload
:s -> :script
:t -> :type
:un -> ?
:where -> undocumented, found by completion, don't know what it is for
```

Comment: @WillNess I try but cant find the answer from `:help`. If you have answer please write it for me.

Comment: for what little I know about this, I arrived at by trial and error. Sorry for misreading your question at first.

Comment: Do you need the list of all unambiguous prefixes? List of commands by how common they are? Or anything else?

Comment: @Yuras Basically I just want to know what `?` would be. Anything other than that would be a plus.

Answer (score 4):

I checked [ghc source file](https://github.com/ghc/ghc/blob/master/ghc/GHCi/UI.hs), and found stdin input is processed by

```
runGHIC -> runGHCiInput -> ghciCompleteWord -> lookupCompletion -> lookupCommand'
```

At the end of [lookupCommand](https://github.com/ghc/ghc/blob/e3ec2e7ae94524ebd111963faf34b84d942265b4/ghc/GHCi/UI.hs#L1238)

```
  -- first, look for exact match (while preferring macros); then, look
  -- for first prefix match (preferring builtins), *unless* a macro
  -- overrides the builtin; see #8305 for motivation
  return $ lookupExact str xcmds <|>
           lookupExact str ghci_cmds <|>
           (builtinPfxMatch >>= \c -> lookupExact (cmdName c) xcmds) <|>
           builtinPfxMatch <|>
           lookupPrefix str xcmds
```

Basically, it first lookup exact match, then prefix match in order. So for normal `:xxx` command, it follows `ghci_cmds` order, which is [availableCommands](https://github.com/ghc/ghc/blob/e3ec2e7ae94524ebd111963faf34b84d942265b4/ghc/GHCi/UI.hs#L160) in `GhciSettings`, i.e.

```
  ("?",         keepGoing help,                 noCompletion),
  ("add",       keepGoingPaths addModule,       completeFilename),
  ("abandon",   keepGoing abandonCmd,           noCompletion),
  ("break",     keepGoing breakCmd,             completeIdentifier),
  ("back",      keepGoing backCmd,              noCompletion),
  ("browse",    keepGoing' (browseCmd False),   completeModule),
  ("browse!",   keepGoing' (browseCmd True),    completeModule),
  ("cd",        keepGoing' changeDirectory,     completeFilename),
  ("check",     keepGoing' checkModule,         completeHomeModule),
  ("continue",  keepGoing continueCmd,          noCompletion),
  ("cmd",       keepGoing cmdCmd,               completeExpression),
  ("ctags",     keepGoing createCTagsWithLineNumbersCmd, completeFilename),
  ("ctags!",    keepGoing createCTagsWithRegExesCmd, completeFilename),
  ("def",       keepGoing (defineMacro False),  completeExpression),
  ("def!",      keepGoing (defineMacro True),   completeExpression),
  ("delete",    keepGoing deleteCmd,            noCompletion),
  ("edit",      keepGoing' editFile,            completeFilename),
  ("etags",     keepGoing createETagsFileCmd,   completeFilename),
  ("force",     keepGoing forceCmd,             completeExpression),
  ("forward",   keepGoing forwardCmd,           noCompletion),
  ("help",      keepGoing help,                 noCompletion),
  ("history",   keepGoing historyCmd,           noCompletion),
  ("info",      keepGoing' (info False),        completeIdentifier),
  ("info!",     keepGoing' (info True),         completeIdentifier),
  ("issafe",    keepGoing' isSafeCmd,           completeModule),
  ("kind",      keepGoing' (kindOfType False),  completeIdentifier),
  ("kind!",     keepGoing' (kindOfType True),   completeIdentifier),
  ("load",      keepGoingPaths loadModule_,     completeHomeModuleOrFile),
  ("load!",     keepGoingPaths loadModuleDefer, completeHomeModuleOrFile),
  ("list",      keepGoing' listCmd,             noCompletion),
  ("module",    keepGoing moduleCmd,            completeSetModule),
  ("main",      keepGoing runMain,              completeFilename),
  ("print",     keepGoing printCmd,             completeExpression),
  ("quit",      quit,                           noCompletion),
  ("reload",    keepGoing' reloadModule,        noCompletion),
  ("reload!",   keepGoing' reloadModuleDefer,   noCompletion),
  ("run",       keepGoing runRun,               completeFilename),
  ("script",    keepGoing' scriptCmd,           completeFilename),
  ("set",       keepGoing setCmd,               completeSetOptions),
  ("seti",      keepGoing setiCmd,              completeSeti),
  ("show",      keepGoing showCmd,              completeShowOptions),
  ("showi",     keepGoing showiCmd,             completeShowiOptions),
  ("sprint",    keepGoing sprintCmd,            completeExpression),
  ("step",      keepGoing stepCmd,              completeIdentifier),
  ("steplocal", keepGoing stepLocalCmd,         completeIdentifier),
  ("stepmodule",keepGoing stepModuleCmd,        completeIdentifier),
  ("type",      keepGoing' typeOfExpr,          completeExpression),
  ("trace",     keepGoing traceCmd,             completeExpression),
  ("undef",     keepGoing undefineMacro,        completeMacro),
  ("unset",     keepGoing unsetOptions,         completeSetOptions),
  ("where",     keepGoing whereCmd,             noCompletion)
```

so `:c` means `:cd`, `:d` means `:def`, follow the order.